How to Set Up export_options.plist for shorebird in Codemagic CI/CD for Flutter?
I’m using Codemagic for CI/CD in a Flutter project and need to configure shorebird for iOS builds. I encountered an issue where the export_options.plist file does not seem to be found or correctly set up.
Here is a snippet of my codemagic.yaml:
- name: Build with for ios
  script: |
    shorebird release ios \
     --export-options-plist=/Users/builder/export_options.plist \
     --build-name=1.0.2

I get the error:

Export options plist /Users/builder/export_options.plist does not set
manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber to false. This is required for
shorebird to work.

Questions:
Where should I place the export_options.plist file in Codemagic?
Should it be in a specific directory or can it be placed anywhere?
How do I ensure that the export_options.plist file is correctly created and accessible during the build process?*
Can you provide an example of how to create and use this file in Codemagic?
Is there a standard way to configure export_options.plist within the Codemagic environment?


Where should I place the export_options.plist file in Codemagic?

The file is generated every build during flutter build ipa command. You should have something like this in your codemagic.yaml file
flutter build ipa --release --export-options-plist=/Users/builder/export_options.plist


Should it be in a specific directory or can it be placed anywhere?

You can use any path, /Users/builder is being used in many examples as it always exists (user home directory) and build process has permissions to create files there.

Can you provide an example of how to create and use this file in Codemagic? Is there a standard way to configure export_options.plist within the Codemagic environment?

additionally to my previous example, I've just read a nice article about Codemagic and Shorebird which inspired me on this answer.

Use this in your setup:
xcode-project use-profiles --custom-export-options={\"manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber\":false}
